# dnu publish does not deploy all image and JavaScript files

Tags: asp.net, dnu

I use the following command to deploy an **ASP.Net core 1.0 MVC application**.

`dnu publish --runtime active --no-source -o e:\website\zigs`

> Issue: Some image files and JavaScript files in the VS2015 project
>   wwwroot 'images' and 'js' folders are not deployed to the
>   'e:\website\zigs\wwwroot\' images and ..js sub-folders.

The missing files are present in the VS2015 project and all works correctly in the development environment.

I currently use **dnvm version 1.0.0-rct1-15540 and dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2**

Is there something I need to do to flag the files to be included in the deployment?
(I can get around it by just manually deploying the missing files, but I would need to have the files deployed automatically by the build/deployment server in the future.)
 Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Make sure the target root folder does not contain any folders/files to do with the deployment before running the dnu publish command!